# TramineR proportion per cluster

Tags: r, dataframe, traminer

I am new to TramineR and using `seqdplot()` command I created a plot to visualize cluster patterns. Is there a way to plot the proportions of each cluster (as seen on the plot below)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the proportion, you can use the `group.p` function of `TraMineRextras`. The function adds the proportion to each group label.

Here is the example given in the help page:

```
library('TraMineRextras')
data(actcal)
actcal <- actcal[1:100,]
actcal.seq <- seqdef(actcal[,13:24])
seqdplot(actcal.seq, group=group.p(actcal$sex))
```

[image]